# Error: Incompatible types in assignment

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, init

I built a class and created a method which initialize all variables.

on .h

```
-(void) initWithX:(float *)x_ andY:(float *)y_ andWidth:(float *)width_;
```

and on .m

```
    -(void) initWithX:(float *)x_ andY:(float *)y_ andWidth:(float *)width_{
    [super init];
    x = x_;  ***
    y = y_;  ***
    width = width_; ***
}
```

Lines with *** give me error "Incompatible types in assignment" but I don't understand: I'm giving 3 floats as told in the .h!!!

Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass your floats by value by removing the `*`:

```
- (void)initWithX:(float)x_ andY:(float)y_ andWidth:(float)width_;

- (void)initWithX:(float)x_ andY:(float)y_ andWidth:(float)width_ {
    [super init];
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    width = width_;
}
```

Otherwise the method is asking for *pointers* to floats (`float *`), and not their actual primitive *values*.

Answer (score 1):

you are asking for float pointers and probably assigning them to float variables. take out the asterisks in the method declarations.